# Using ORMLite with Fragments

Tags: android-fragments, ormlite, android-fragmentactivity

Is it possible to use ORMLite to manage your local database while using Android Fragments?

Some example code or links to example code showing how to create something like an ORMLiteFragmentActivity class would be cool.  Or I guess a simple "no" might be an acceptable answer.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yup, it's totally possible.  See the instructions [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#SEC40).  Basically, all you do is create a new class, like you suggested.  You can replace `Fragment` with any other type that you want to extend.  For example, I also have `OrmLiteListFragment` which extends `ListFragment`

```
public class OrmLiteFragment extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;

    protected DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
        if (databaseHelper == null) {
            databaseHelper =
                OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);
        }
        return databaseHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (databaseHelper != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
            databaseHelper = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this yield some "ormlite helper was already closed and is being re-opened" logging. So I feel that may not be the right event to override. What do you think?

Answer (score -1):

you can operate ormlite db  only after onstart() is called

[sorry,i an new at stackoverflow](http://my.oschina.net/zengliubao/blog/528132)    http://my.oschina.net/zengliubao/blog/528132